# marker-end doesn't follow a direction of the path

Tags: svg

Have a code:

```
<svg id="view-svg-problem"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <marker id='svg-marker-start' orient='auto' markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth='10' markerHeight='10' refX='9' refY='5' class="svg-path-dec">
              <rect  x="1" y="1" width="8" height="8" />
              <text  x="3" y="7.1" font-weight="bold" font-family="Arial" font-size="5.5" fill="white" stroke="transparent">S</text>
        </marker>


        <marker id='svg-marker-end' orient='auto' markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth='10' markerHeight='10' refX='5' refY='9' class="svg-path-dec">
              <rect  x="1" y="1" width="8" height="8" />
              <text  x="3" y="7.1" font-weight="bold" font-family="Arial" font-size="5.5" fill="white" stroke="transparent">F</text>
        </marker>
    </defs> 

    <path id="view-path-svg" class="svg-path" marker-start="url(#svg-marker-start)" marker-end="url(#svg-marker-end)" d="M 655,343 Q747,317 705.5,311 Q664,305 708,292 Q752,279 713.5,254 Q675,229 711.5,212.5 Q748,196 706.5,189 Q665,182 687,157.5 Q709,133 679.5,126.5 Q650,120 663,106 T676,92"></path>
</svg>
```

So result looks like on the picture:

[image]

Easy to see that `marker-start` aligns well with the path, but `marker-end` doesn't want to. Is there a solution to the problem?

Comment: You've not provided the path data in the question i.e. the contents of the d attribute. How on earth could we diagnose what's wrong without that.

Comment: fixed code in the post. didn't know that can be a cause.

Comment: seems that the last `T` piece is the cause, when i changed it to `L` all works fine.

Comment: Indeed, it's all about exactly what that T does right at the end. Is the line being drawn vertically then, I think it is but you'd have to go through the maths for it to prove it.

Comment: do you mean mathematics behind bezier curve rendering?

Comment: Pretty much yes. Starting from here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataQuadraticBezierCommands

Comment: yeah, that's where i found the answer that i used `T` wrongly